# Create a jgw file for jpg image.

Tags: openlayers-2, raster, georeferencing, jpg

I converted ecw file into jpg file with IrfanView, to display the jpg as base layer in openlayers.
I understood that I need to create a jgw file to display the jpg file.

I found this example:

```
 4.23214625853148 - A
 0.00000000000000 - D
 0.00000000000000 - B
-4.23214625853148 - E
 3404018.70881921 - C
 5819863.55539414 - F
```

for F - i know the left up corner coordinates(in Israel TM projection), i need other projection?

I did not understand what is the other parameter:
A is the x scale length in meters? and E its the negative?
And about D and B I have no idea.

The file is little bit big: about 300 MB, its will be a problem in openlayers?

Comment: All but your last question are answered at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2008/coordinates-of-upper-left-corner-in-the-world-file/2010#2010.  I found this by searching our site on [world file parameters](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=world+file+parameters), where you can find other threads discussing this.

Comment: updated this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file D and B are rotation factors

Comment: Actually you should start over. The Ecw file contains projection info in the header. Lizardtech has a free viewer and I think you can convert files under 500 mb.